# How to fix duplicate title tag in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am facing the issues there are two title tags displaying in view source page. In Symfony Kindly help in this ..

In Config.yml (site_title) when I am changing the title that also not changing..

TIA,

Comment: Which Version ?? 2 or 1.4, it's totally different....

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app\Resources\views` and verify your `layout.html.twig` in this line:

```
<title>{% block title %}anything{% endblock %}</title>
```